# Usando python e django, problema com querys

Tags: python, query, django

Eu estou usando Python com o framework Django. Este método deve retornar uma query resultante, para enviar e-mail para os e-mails correspondentes do banco de dados. Porém, o método funciona para alguns casos e para outros não.

```
from django.db.models import Q

def membrosBancaAtual(semestre):
    semestre = semestre.filter(atual = True)
    disciplina = Disciplina.objects.filter(semestre = semestre)
    projetos = ProjetoDeGraduacao.objects.filter(disciplina__in = disciplina)
    query = Q(banca2__in = projetos)
    return query
```

Alguém tem idéia do porquê pra alguns casos funciona e outros não?

Comment: `query = Q(banca2__in=projetos)` não era pra estar dentro de um `Model.objects.filter()`?

Comment: Como assim? Você pode dar um exemplo? Eu fiz outras funções parecidas com essa, todas tinham esse tipo e funcionaram quando eu testei.

Comment: Você quer enviar e-mails para os membros da banca, você deve retorna a lista de membros, você está apenas retornado `Q(banca2__in=projetos)`.

Comment: Mas por que pra um e-mail envia e pra outros não? E também fiz outros métodos que nem este, mudando apenas a linha do "query" e funcionou quando testei, enviaram os e-mails. Que lista de membros você se refere? Eu já fui filtrando a query com as outras variáveis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua query deve ser utilizada em uma consulta:

```
Model.objects.filter(banca2__in=projetos)
```

.
Esse return query joga a query para onde?

Comment: Então, mas nessa linha `query = Q(banca2__in = projetos)` eu achei que deveria usar objeto Q, pois ele serve para querys mais complexas, pelo que entendi lendo a documentação do Django. Para outros métodos que fiz, que também são querys que selecionam algo do banco de dados e aí manda e-mail para essas pessoas, estão feitos nesse mesmo jeito.

Comment: Esse return vai para esse filtro:
`QUERYLIST = {
   '1':['Enviar e-mail para alunos Matriculados no semestre atual',alunosMatriculadosAtual],
   '2':['Enviar e-mail para alunos inscritos (projeto submetido)',alunosInscritosAtual],
   '3':['Enviar e-mail para docentes Responsaveis do semestre atual',docentesResponsaveisAtual],
   '4':['Enviar e-mail para supervisores do semestre atual',supervisoresResponsaveisAtual],
   '5':['Enviar e-mail para orientadores do semestre atual',orientadoresResponsaveisAtual],
   '6':['Enviar e-mail para membros da banca do semestre atual',membrosBancaAtual]
   }`

Comment: Usando sua sugestão, o Django deu esse retorno como erro: global name 'Model' is not defined

Comment: Também usei `Banca.objects.filter(banca2__in=projetos)`, que Banca é o nome da tabela e deu o memso erro.

Comment: Essa função usa a opção escolhida do filtro: 
        `def options():
 list =[]
 for key,option in QUERYLIST.iteritems():
  list.append((key,option[0]))
 OPCOES = tuple(list)
 return OPCOES`

Comment: Essa outra também usa o filtro:
`def send_emails(options,departamento, assunto = None,corpo = None):
 if options != []:
  options = literal_eval(options)
  query = Q()
  semestre = Semestre.objects.filter(grupo = departamento)
  for item in options:
   f = QUERYLIST[item][1]
   query.add(f(semestre), query.OR)
  usuarios = User().objects.filter(query)
  dispatch(usuarios,assunto, corpo)`

Comment: O `Model` do meu exemplo é para você substituir pelo model que você está utilizando, no caso `Banca`.
Esse erro de global name 'Banca' is not defined, é porque provavelmente você não importou o model lá em cima.
`from sua_app.models import Banca'

Comment: Obrigado cara. Era justamente essa linha que estava faltando no método. Agora está funcionando!!!

Comment: Marca a resposta como ok :)

Comment: Eu não consigo clicar na setinha pra cima. Pelo que entendi falta reputação pra mim. Onde consegui clicar, eu não sei se é o de Ok